# netsh http add urlacl via Group Policy (GPO)

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, netsh

I have self-hosted WCF application that needs to listen on a URL on port 80.  In order to do this, I need to add an entry to the HTTP.sys url list for a given user.

I can do this with `netsh http add urlacl` or calling a Win32 API directly (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851161/net-or-win32-equivalent-of-netsh-http-add-urlacl-command).  Neither of these are really desirable, as both require administrative rights and are specific to a particular user.

**Is there an equivalent group policy setting to configure HTTP or some other way to centrally configure this?**

Answer (score 0):

In manual (netsh http add urlacl gives you more info) user parameter is said to be the user or user-group name.

Comment: Yes, it can be a user or group, but it is specific to a given machine and must be executed on that machine.  The key point I am looking for is central configuration (i.e., the admin can configure this without actually logging on to the given machine).

Comment: The admin can create a startup script with the command. As usual in Group Policy, computers could be filtered by their organizaitonal unit or by the group they belong to.